# How do I completely deactivate the Screen Keyboard?

Tags: touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard

So, when I go to settings, in Accesibility, the option for the Screen Keyboard is off. But whenever y touch the screen (my laptop allows me to) on a website and there is any element of text, the keyboard shows up.

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Laptop model: DELL Inspiron 15 5579 2-in-1

How can I fix this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps you could add more info like, os version, laptop version and what have you done to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: @MatsK I already added the OS version and my laptop model, but I haven't done anything to troubleshoot the issue

Comment: Take a look here, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1723857